In Rust, what is the real benefit of Pin?
I understand the purpose of Pin is to prevent a value being moved. But in order to correctly use Pin::new_unchecked(), one need to make a lot of promises (e.g.  "the value’s data will not be moved nor have its storage invalidated until it gets dropped", DerefMut::deref_mut and Deref::deref on the pointer type Ptr should uphold the pinning invariants, and "the reference Ptr dereferences to will not be moved out of again" see also https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.new_unchecked). Otherwise, the compiler cannot guarantee the data is pinned.
Since the caller need to make the above promises anyway, why not just not using Pin and just make the promises? What benefits does Pin actually bring beyond just a semantic marker?

Pin::new_unchecked() is not really meant to be used by end-users; it's more of an implementation detail inside of libraries. The easiest way to create a pinned object by an enduser is to put an object on the heap, using Box::pin. I also wrote a lengthy article on some of the thoughts and intentions behind Pin, maybe that helps.

"why not just not using Pin and just make the promises" - because Rust without unsafe is guaranteed to be free of undefined behaviour. So there has to be a mechanism in the language that represents that 'promise' that the compiler can check in safe code. That's why Pin::new_unchecked() is unsafe, because it indicates that the library programmer who uses it is responsible for upholding soundness. Then, another library using the Pin object can rely on it without breaking soundness.

But again, if you are an enduser and not a library programmer who actually creates pinned objects on a lower level, please don't use Pin::new_unchecked(). Use Box::pin() or std::pin::pin!() instead.


Since the caller need to make the above promises anyway, why not just not using Pin and just make the promises?

The entire point of the Pin type is to communicate these promises between different pieces of (unsafe) code.
Within a single module or crate, you can decide whatever you want about how things work and what properties are guaranteed. But, when you want to interact with other crates and use such promises from unsafe code, you have to do one of these things:

Make your functions unsafe and document how they must be used.
/// Safety: ...
pub unsafe fn do_thing_with_pinned_value(value: *mut Foo) {...}


Constrain the input by using a type that guarantees the needed property.
pub fn do_thing_with_pinned_value(value: Pin<&mut Foo>) {...}



In this sense, Pin is not that much different from any other Rust type. For example, if your function takes a &[bool] then that type promises that the memory pointed to is readable, not going to be mutated, and contains valid bools. You could use (*const bool, usize) instead of &[bool], and your code would function exactly the same but the compiler could not catch as many bugs.
As I see it, the reason that Pin feels more mysterious than this is that it provides a guarantee which is less often needed, and whose need is much more dependent on the specific type relying on it. Let me put it in more parallel terms:

&mut Foo promises that it points to a valid Foo.
Pin<&mut Foo> promises that it points to a valid Foo that is pinned.

The latter is useless if Foo doesn't have any operations that depend on pinning, but it's useful if Foo does in fact depend on pinning and is being used by multiple crates.
In the common case of Futures, futures are defined by crates, depend on being pinned (async blocks in particular need pinning for their local variables), and then usually given to other crates that execute them. So, Pin is a way for the executor crate to communicate to the future implementor crate that the future is in fact pinned.
If we didn't have Pin, then Future::poll would have to be an unsafe fn, which would mean that all executors and future combinators would have to be unsafe code. By having Pin, we reduce the amount of unsafe code to:

Code that performs pinning — ensures that a value it owns won't move, then creates a Pin promising that.
Code that makes use of pinning — relying on the value not moving in a way that would be UB if it did.


And even the code that use Pin can encapsulate the unsafe code with tools like pin!(), Box::pin() and pin-project.

Pin is an enforcable contract that prevents moving. If I make a Box<MyType> and declare that "MyType is self referential and cannot be moved", the compiler will not stop the user from doing *my_type_box and moving the value anyway. Making it a Pin<Box<MyType>> will actually ensure that cannot happen by restricting access via &mut MyType and derefs. That is benefit of Pin regardless how its made.
Pin::new_unchecked is a raw way to create a Pin wrapper but since it is generic over any Deref type, the function signature itself cannot guarantee that the rest of Pin's contract is upheld. There are examples in the documentation that show how the contract could be broken. Thus it is marked unsafe and requires the user to provide those guarantees.
However, Pin::new_unchecked is not the only way to create a Pin-d value, and actually the most common and totally safe way is via Box::pin. Box can make this guarantee on its own since its value is owned and unique. And as mentioned in the comments std::pin::pin! is another safe way to make a pinned value for things on the stack.
So nothing is forcing you to use Pin::new_unchecked and burden yourself with those restrictions.
